# How delete item's sortable JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the program where there is a accordion with three item.

In the first item's accordion there is one sortable and there is one button, after clicking above, I would like to I delete an item's sortable.

How to delete the item with id="three"???(EXAMPLE)

I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can remove the `#three` element with [`.remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method. for ex,

```
$('#r').click(function(){
    $('#three').remove();
});
```